# Chrome print exact measurements

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've created a page that I would like to print using the chrome browser. Everything seems to work fine. However, the borders printed are not exactly the measurement I provided. Please refer to the images below.

What it looks like on my screen:

[image]

What chrome prints:

[image: chrome print]

Notice the difference between the width of the lines, on the left side.

How do I force chrome to print exactly what is on my screen? Especially the border measurements.

Previously I had difficulty printing background-color: however, I used:

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
```

Now the black background prints. Is there a similar solution for borders?

Comment: You might already know this, but In dev-tools, you can open the "Rendering" tab under "more tools". At the bottom, you can select to emulate CSS media. Via that, you can select print. This way, you can see and modify real-time instead of having to "print" all the time. I do not know how to fix your issue, but thought this might come handy for you or future people reading this question.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm sure someone will definitely benefit from this :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just encountered the same Error and found a solution!

In my code I set the print zoom to 50% and this lead to borders with 1px beeing twice as big, to resolve the issue i just deleted the 50% statment, if you have not changed your zoom anywhere maby it would work if you set the zoom to 200%.

That was my code(scss):

```
@media print {
  body {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    color-adjust: exact;
    //zoom: 50%;
  }

  .no-print {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```